# SharePoint Online Tasks and Outlook 2013/2016

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation

I would like to sync a SharePoint Online Task list with Outlook 2013/2016 and then filter the tasks to only

> Display items assigned to the current user and the status of the task
>   to not equal completed.

Is this possible? Can someone direct me in the right direction?

I can sync the list but the filters in Outlook aren't working !